Laravel eloquent relationship with binary SQL Server
I have 2 tables in SQL Server.
Table Account:
[id] [binary](13) NOT NULL, [PRIMARI KEY]
[email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
....

Table Status:
[numG] [int NOT NULL,
[id] [binary](13) NOT NULL, [PRIMARI KEY]
[contractname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
....

Here is the relation in AccountModel:
public function status(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->BelongsTo(StatusModel::class, 'id', 'id');
}

StatusModel:
public function account(): HasOne
{
    return $this->HasOne(AccountModel::class, 'id', 'id');
}

CheckController:
public function checkStatus($id) {
    $account= AccountModel::where('id', DB::raw("convert(binary(13), '$id')"))->with('status')->first();
    dd($account)
}

This is returning null :
#attributes: array:21 [▼
    "id" => "testUser\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    "email" => "test@test.com"
  ]
 #relations: array:1 [▼
    "account" => null
  ]

I have tried to print using eloquent
dd($account->status->numG)

But it throws an error :

Attempt to read property "numG" on null

I want to search for data by id from table account and get numG from table status.
Something like this
$data = [
    "id" => $account->id,
    "email" => $account->email
    "numG" => $account->status->numG
]

Any suggestions on how to handle binary data from SQL Server in Laravel?

FYI, SQL Server 2008 reached End of Life around 5 years ago; you really need to implement that finalised upgrade plan you had about 6 years ago.

I'd like to know the reason you using binary(13) as a primary with the data "testUser\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" it might be easier to store the binary data in a separate field and stick to int keys.

Do you realize that "testUser\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" is a binary(18) value that you're trying to store/query against a binary(13) column? There seem to be some missing/incorrect details here.

@Tony i am working in existing database. the client already have desktop application 13 years old. i think why they use binary is they read the id with byte. but the real reason is i dont know its 13 years old application, i just got the job to make simple web app on that database .
@AlwaysLearning soory its my mistake, i am not copying it directly from dd($user) the correct is binary(13) i am double check it

@AlwaysLearning also i wonder in sql i run query using convert(varchar(13), id)  and returning 0x74657374557365720000000000
but my model is not using any convert attribute or my controller just print it as string with \x00 as null without convert anything.
